# sortwith one of the POJO values?

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, pojo

I have random pojo values, and I want to sort by one of the POJO values, the structure of the values ​​I want to sort is as follows: A-1, A-2, A-3, A-4, A-5, .. .

I've tried to sort it but the value is really in order only between A-1 to A-9, while the value for A-10 is always under A-1.

here's the code I use:

```
temp.sortWith { lhs, rhs ->
  rhs?.blok_kamar?.let {
  lhs?.blok_kamar?.compareTo(
    it, false
  )}!!
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how lexicographical ordering works. `"1000"` is less than `"2"`, despite `1000` being greater than `2`. Look at the quotes. It seems like your `A-1`, `A-2`, ..., `A-10` are `String`s. You need to extract the numbers from those identifiers and compare them as `Int`s:

```
data class Data(val id: String)

fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf(
        Data("A-1"),
        Data("A-10"),
        Data("A-2"),
        Data("A-30"),
        Data("A-3")
    )

    list.sortBy { it.id.substring(it.id.indexOf("-") + 1).toInt() }
    println(list)
}
```

This prints:

> ```
> [Data(id=A-1), Data(id=A-2), Data(id=A-3), Data(id=A-10), Data(id=A-30)]
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for helping to solve the problem I was facing :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code I do not know what temp actually is, so here is an idea to give you a start, based on a list:

```
val result = list
  .sortedBy {
    it.id.substringBefore("-") + "-" + it.id.substringAfter("-").padStart(3, '0')
  }
```